# Is there a method when IProgress is 100%

Tags: c#

I need in my software to download in mp3 format a youtube video.
For this, I use the library https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplod . In the download command there is an optional parameter `IProgress`:

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNvMw.png)

But I've never heard IProgress before, so I was wondering: how do I know if the `IProgress` value is 100%?

Here is the code:

```
var youtube = new YoutubeClient();

var streamManifest = await youtube.Videos.Streams.GetManifestAsync(ytURL);
var streamInfo = streamManifest.GetAudioOnly().WithHighestBitrate();

if (streamInfo != null)
{
    // Download the stream to file
    await youtube.Videos.Streams.DownloadAsync(streamInfo, Utilities.songPath + @"\" + songNameWithArtist + ".mp3", cancellationToken:cancelDownload);                         
}
```

Comment: There's the [ProgressChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1.progresschanged) event. That being said, when the progress reaches 100%, the method should return anyway. So, in most situations, you don't really need to check if it reaches 100%. You just continue with the next step once the method has returned.

Comment: Note that the method might report 100% progress but still has some "finishing business" to do and you probably want to wait for everything to complete before executing the next step. Moreover, if the progress value isn't calculated accurately (though it should be), it might never reach 100% and only comes very close to it (e.g., 99.99%).

Comment: welp no there isn't ^^' https://ibb.co/Dzy121T

Comment: The event belongs to [the class that implements the interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress), not to the interface itself. And you access it from the caller method (which passes the `Progress<T>` object), not from the callee.

Comment: So how am-I supposed to do ? I dont really understand there is no event in the caller method :/

Comment: Well, then [edit] the question and provide a [repro]. You asked how to check if the progress has reached 100% and I've answered that (in a general way). Your current code doesn't even have an instance of `IProgress<T>`. We need to see where it is, where it comes from, and where exactly you want to check for the progress.

Comment: As a side note, I did not downvote your question but you should probably read [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/8967612) I have removed the sentence from your last edit because it doesn't help and is likely to get you even more downvotes.

Comment: Give all the class you coded and we will include the code you are interested in with explanation.

Comment: no? everything you need is on the post.

Comment: To handle progress changes, you just need to provide an implementation of `IProgress<double>`. You can create one like this: `new Progress<double>(progress => /* do something with the new progress value */)`. But if you're interested only in it reaching 100%, then, like others said, you can just await the method -- its completion implies that the progress reached 100%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I know if the IProgress value is 100%?

The returned task is completed, and the method continues executing after the `await`.

E.g.:

```
await youtube.Videos.Streams.DownloadAsync(streamInfo, filename, progress, cancellationToken:cancelDownload);
// Operation is completed when the code gets here
```

As noted in the comments, `IProgress` may not ever get to 100%. Also, if this is not a UI application, you may receive progress reports *after* the operation has completed; these extra progress reports should just be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, finally someone intelligent ^^ :)